# Convert ctype Array to bytearray

Tags: python, c, arrays

I have a C function that takes a pointer (for output) to the following structure:

```
class MacFrame(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("buffer", ctypes.c_ubyte * 128),
                ("length", ctypes.c_ubyte),
                ("nodeid", ctypes.c_uint)]
```

Then, I need to make the following Python function that calls the C function converts the buffer and length field to a `bytearray` object to return it, but I am unclear on what the syntax should be:

```
def recv(self, bufsize):
    frame = MacFrame()

    self.Api.otListenerRead(ctypes.byref(frame))

    return bytearray(frame.buffer, frame.length), frame.nodeid
```

I know the `bytearray(frame.buffer, frame.length)` is incorrect, but I don't know what the best way is.

Comment: Depends on your definition of best, but would `bytearray(frame.buffer)[:frame.length]` suffice?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to retag your question because the first code snippet is in `c++`.

Comment: By best, I meant most efficient (a minimum amount of copying). But I will take the 'best' answer I am provided with.

Comment: @hmofrad, both code snippets are Python.

Comment: @Nick Banks, Oops! My bad, I thought, it's a c code block!

Comment: `bytearray(frame.buffer)[:frame.length]` would to my understanding create 2 copies. To avoid this you could use [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview): `return bytearray(memoryview(frame.buffer)[:frame.length]), frame.nodeid`